# PHP bizarre math

Tags: php, math, variables

I'm getting unexpected values for variable calculations:

```
$var1 = $var2 * (((1 + $var3)^$var4)^$var5);
```

I've verified that `$var2` is 3, `$var3` is 0.1, `$var4` is 1, `$var5` is 1.1 so,

`$var1 = 3*(((1+0.1)^1)^1.1) = 3.3316` but in PHP, `$var1 = 3`

if I change `$var4` to 2,

`$var1 =  3*(((1+0.1)^1)^1.1) = 3.6999` but in PHP, `$var1 = 6`

Why is this?  Any ideas?  I've tried explicitly declaring all variables as floats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that `^` is not "power of". You may want to have a look at [**the pow function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php).

(`^` is actually "[bitwise exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)".)

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Come on, enough with the up-voting. It's not rocket science. ;)

Comment: this catches out a lot of newcomers to PHP (and even some more experienced folk from time to time).